# How can I jump across the bridge?

Tags: half-life-2, half-life-2-episode-two

I'm playing Half-Life 2 Episode 2 and I need to get this car to the other side of the bridge. Perhaps I'm missing something dead obvious, but how on earth do I do this?

[image]

**Update:**

It seemed some in-game event triggered the bridge to move, when I reloaded the game it was pointing the right way. But if you jump on the middle part (there's another part behind this one), it triggers the event where the bridge tilts. So jumping to get the cars out of the way seems a no-go.

[image]

Ok, now I'm officially lost:

[image]

Since I didn't trust the current answers, I went looking elsewhere to find it myself. It seems it was fine that the bridge was 'tilted upwards', so I decided to play along, move the cars and 'tilt it back'. Nothing happens!

Comment: I came in here expecting to answer Gravity Gun, but then I found out it wasn't an actual baby. Shame.

Comment: Try knocking them off entirely? You 100% have to move the cars for this in some capacity...

Comment: I actually did manage it now, but I simply replayed back to the original shockwave. I guess I broke some in game sequence, because even when I cleared the bridge, it didn't seem to want to tilt :S

Comment: I'll replay it again from a save game to see whether I triggered the tilting the wrong way perhaps, because I did try the knocking off as well and it didn't seem to do anything...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I remember correctly you need to get out on the middle span and get it to tilt down towards this span, like a seesaw - it's got a bunch of heavy crap tilting it the other way that can be knocked off with the gravity gun.

It's been a few years, though.  That might be total malarkey.

Answer (score 11):

If I'm remembering this part correctly, you should be able to cross to the other side of the bridge on foot.  Rearrange the cars with the Gravity Gun so that the weight causes the bridge to tip down, then you can drive across.

Comment: Ha!  Simultaneous "if I remember correctly".

Comment: @lilserf - Ha indeed! +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the cars are not tipping the bridge over as expected, you can push them off completely and be the only one standing on the bridge. It defies physics, but the game was coded so that you wouldn't get stuck if you knocked everything off.